# How to order the query result by count() of field in postgresql without group by

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have simple database and I thing my answer should be so simple but I can't find my answer the db is look like:

```
-----------------
name | ip
-----------------
nick |192.168.1.10
john |192.168.1.1
john |192.168.1.2
john |192.168.1.3
lucy |192.168.10.1
lucy |192.168.10.2
```

I need a query that return all the rows but the result sorted by count(ip) per name
and the result of above list should be something like :

```
------------------
name |ip
------------------
nick |192.168.1.10
lucy |192.168.10.1
lucy |192.168.10.2
john |192.168.1.1
john |192.168.1.2
john |192.168.1.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this query:

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM   table1 t1 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT Count(name) counter, 
                          name 
                   FROM   table1 
                   GROUP  BY name)t2 
               ON t1.name = t2.name 
ORDER  BY counter;
```

*[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/199f3/5)*

Comment: it's worked fine except I had to change some of the table and field name in addition the "name" is a reserved keyword in pgsql :) thanks

Comment: you are welcome my friend,if it is the true answer then click on it as true answer ;)

Comment: please fix your answer (the count() should be on IP field) I checked it as true answer

Comment: Thanks my friend,there is not any difference between using `count(*)` or `count(name)` or `count(ip)` here because all of them will count the rows which are `group by name`.

Answer (score 1):

Here a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/42219/10)

Try this statement.

```
SELECT * FROM tblSAMPLE ORDER BY name DESC,ip
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT NAME,IP,
       COUNT(NAME) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY NAME) 
               OVER (PARTITION BY NAME) "Answer"
FROM PSQL
ORDER BY 3
```

Ans By
Subash M

Need to tell correct answer Y/N?

Comment: I have got ERROR:  syntax error at or near "(" on your query

Comment: the `keep ...` is Oracle specific and not supported by Postgres

Answer (score 0):

This should be faster than a self join on the table.

```
select name, ip
from (
  select name,
         ip,
         count(*) over (partition by name) as cnt
  from the_table
) t
order by cnt;
```